# GEE function returns scalar instead of the image dimensions

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

In the function CFmean, I want the 'cf' variable to be calculated so it has the same dimensions as the images in my dataset (element wise), all the other functions I have written in the past did this automatically but with this function it just returns a scalar value. The geometry is arbitrary of course.

```
// import geometry (point to zoom in to)
var home_coords = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(
  [29.726282300760264,0.11470130422188105,
  29.78310221653175,0.16911779176188482]) // please fill in correct expression

// load image stack for one year
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V20/NOAH/G025/T3H')
  .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2010-01-31')
  .filterBounds(home_coords)
//  .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31');

// extract air temperature, SW radiation for one year
var AirTemperature = dataset.select('Tair_f_inst');
var Irradiation_ShortWave = dataset.select('SWdown_f_tavg'); //Swnet_tavg, SWdown_f_tavg
var WindSpeed = dataset.select('Wind_f_inst');

// take composite (yearly mean) of irradiation and air temp and put in different bands of image
var T_G_comp = ee.Image(AirTemperature.mean())
    .addBands(ee.Image(Irradiation_ShortWave.mean()));

// print graphs
print(ui.Chart.image.doySeries(Irradiation_ShortWave, home_coords, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30));
print(ui.Chart.image.doySeries(WindSpeed, home_coords, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30));

print(dataset.select('SWdown_f_tavg'))

var CFmean = function(image) {
  var cf_per_image = image.expression(
    '(1-(beta*(c1+(c2*T)+(c3*G)-Tref))+(gamma*log10(G + 1)))*(G/Gref)', 
   //'(1-(0.0045*(-3.75+(1.14*T)+(0.0175*G)-25))+(0.1*log10(G + 1)))*(G/1000)'
   //'(1-(beta*(c1+(c2*T)+(c3*G)-Tref))+(gamma*log10(G + 1)))*(G/Gref)'
    {
      'G': image.select('SWdown_f_tavg'),
      'T': image.select('Tair_f_inst'),
      'beta': 0.0045,
      'gamma': 0.1,
      'c1': -3.75,
      'c2': 1.14,
      'c3': 0.0175,
      'Tref': 25,
      'Gref': 1000, 
    }).set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start')).rename('cf');
  return image.addBands(cf_per_image)
};



var miauw = dataset.map(CFmean)

print(miauw)
```

Comment: Your example is incomplete, so it's not possible to recreate or diagnose the problem.

Comment: What is exactly incomplete? Because for me the code runs perfect, the cf band is just returned as a single value instead of the proper dimensions like the input bands.